ImportError: Using `bitsandbytes` 8-bit quantization requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate` and the latest version of bitsandbytes: `pip instal
This is my code.
import torch

llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
    context_window=4096,
    max_new_tokens=256,
    generate_kwargs={"temperature": 0, "do_sample": False},
    system_prompt=system_prompt,
    query_wrapper_prompt=query_wrapper_prompt,
    tokenizer_name="mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1",
    model_name="mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1",
    device_map="auto",
    tokenizer_kwargs={"max_length": 4096},
    # uncomment this if using CUDA to reduce memory usage
    model_kwargs={
        "torch_dtype": torch.float16, 
        "llm_int8_enable_fp32_cpu_offload": True,
        "bnb_4bit_quant_type": 'nf4',
        "bnb_4bit_use_double_quant":True,
        "bnb_4bit_compute_dtype":torch.bfloat16,
        "load_in_4bit": True}
)

I got this error.
The load_in_4bit and load_in_8bit arguments are deprecated and will be removed in the future versions. Please, pass a BitsAndBytesConfig object in quantization_config argument instead.
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 3
      1 import torch
----> 3 llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
      4     context_window=4096,
      5     max_new_tokens=256,
      6     generate_kwargs={"temperature": 0, "do_sample": False},
      7     system_prompt=system_prompt,
      8     query_wrapper_prompt=query_wrapper_prompt,
      9     tokenizer_name="mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1",
     10     model_name="mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1",
     11     device_map="auto",
     12     tokenizer_kwargs={"max_length": 4096},
     13     # uncomment this if using CUDA to reduce memory usage
     14     model_kwargs={
     15         "torch_dtype": torch.float16, 
     16         "llm_int8_enable_fp32_cpu_offload": True,
     17         "bnb_4bit_quant_type": 'nf4',
     18         "bnb_4bit_use_double_quant":True,
     19         "bnb_4bit_compute_dtype":torch.bfloat16,
     20         "load_in_4bit": True}
     21 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/llms/huggingface/base.py:161, in HuggingFaceLLM.__init__(self, context_window, max_new_tokens, query_wrapper_prompt, tokenizer_name, model_name, model, tokenizer, device_map, stopping_ids, tokenizer_kwargs, tokenizer_outputs_to_remove, model_kwargs, generate_kwargs, is_chat_model, callback_manager, system_prompt, messages_to_prompt, completion_to_prompt, pydantic_program_mode, output_parser)
    159 """Initialize params."""
    160 model_kwargs = model_kwargs or {}
--> 161 self._model = model or AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    162     model_name, device_map=device_map, **model_kwargs
    163 )
    165 # check context_window
    166 config_dict = self._model.config.to_dict()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py:561, in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    557         cls.register(config.__class__, model_class, exist_ok=True)
    558     return model_class.from_pretrained(
    559         pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **hub_kwargs, **kwargs
    560     )
--> 561 elif type(config) in cls._model_mapping.keys():
    562     model_class = _get_model_class(config, cls._model_mapping)
    563     return model_class.from_pretrained(
    564         pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **hub_kwargs, **kwargs
    565     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py:3024, in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, config, cache_dir, ignore_mismatched_sizes, force_download, local_files_only, token, revision, use_safetensors, *model_args, **kwargs)
   3005     config_path = config if config is not None else pretrained_model_name_or_path
   3006     config, model_kwargs = cls.config_class.from_pretrained(
   3007         config_path,
   3008         cache_dir=cache_dir,
   (...)
   3019         **kwargs,
   3020     )
   3021 else:
   3022     # In case one passes a config to `from_pretrained` + "attn_implementation"
   3023     # override the `_attn_implementation` attribute to `attn_implementation` of the kwargs
-> 3024     # Please see: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/28038
   3025 
   3026     # Overwrite `config._attn_implementation` by the one from the kwargs --> in auto-factory
   3027     # we pop attn_implementation from the kwargs but this handles the case where users
   3028     # passes manually the config to `from_pretrained`.
   3029     config = copy.deepcopy(config)
   3031     kwarg_attn_imp = kwargs.pop("attn_implementation", None)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/quantizers/quantizer_bnb_4bit.py:62, in Bnb4BitHfQuantizer.validate_environment(self, *args, **kwargs)
     60 def validate_environment(self, *args, **kwargs):
     61     if not (is_accelerate_available() and is_bitsandbytes_available()):
---> 62         raise ImportError(
     63             "Using `bitsandbytes` 8-bit quantization requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate` "
     64             "and the latest version of bitsandbytes: `pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes`"
     65         )
     67     if kwargs.get("from_tf", False) or kwargs.get("from_flax", False):
     68         raise ValueError(
     69             "Converting into 4-bit or 8-bit weights from tf/flax weights is currently not supported, please make"
     70             " sure the weights are in PyTorch format."
     71         )

ImportError: Using bitsandbytes 8-bit quantization requires Accelerate: pip install accelerate and the latest version of bitsandbytes: pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes
what is the issue of this

was this issue resolved ? I am getting similar issues with no solution found

The exception was rised for is_accelerate_available() and is_bitsandbytes_available()
So,
I also had the same issue, uninstalling and reinstalling conda-forge and accelerate helped
conda install -c conda-forge accelerate

